# Changing layout is difficult or easy in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, document-classes

I am new to LaTeX. I am writing an article in LaTeX but at the moment I am not sure what should be the final layout of my article; so, I am writing it in `IEEEtran` format. I thought that it would be easy to change the layout later if required.

But I read a book on LaTeX and I found the following line written in it which has made me worried:

> "Although some parameters can be adjusted within a predefined document layout, the design of a whole new layout is difficult and takes a lot of time."

So, is it true that it will be difficult for me to change the layout later?

### Addendum

Just now I saw that if I change the line `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` to `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`, then I get so many errors for the keywords related to `IEEEtran`.

Comment: Well, the *design* of a good layout takes time and more importantly skill. Just switching layouts usually is easy, even though there might be complications like layout-specific commands or a change of the top sectioning level (i.e. chapter vs. section).

Comment: different publishers have built different layouts into their document classes.  if they followed good practices, and maintained the basic sectioning philosophy, the changes needed to migrate from one document class to another (of the same general level, i.e. different article classes) should be limited to relatively small areas, such as the top matter.  before settling on one class, it might be wise to find out the practices and requirements of publishers in your subject area.

Comment: yeah just now i saw that if i change the line `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` with `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}` then i get soo many erros for the keywords related to `IEEEtran`

Comment: You may be mixing up two perspectives -- that of the end-user and that of a document class designer. As long as the end-user hasn't engaged in too much visual formatting, switching from one design to an other is generally accomplished by switching the document class -- say, from `article` to `IEEEtran`. (Of course, specific classes may offer macros that aren't available in others, in which case switching classes may require some macro programming.) Conversely, designing a new class is not easy, in part because it involves both LaTeX programming skills and a flair for good layout and design.

Comment: If you don't know what the final layout will be, I think it is best to stick to a standard class (e.g. `article`) and load as few packages as possible i.e. mess with the layout as little as possible and use as few non-standard macros as possible. Then it is easier to switch layout and finalise your document later. I don't necessarily practise this, but I do think I should!

Comment: If you use a class designed for a specific journal or publisher such as ieetran then there are likely to be some publisher-specific fromtmatter cpmmands. One of the standard classes is probably a better "generic" base. However even starting from ieetran changing to any other class is only likely to involve changing a few lines. Ignore the _number_ of errors, often all errors after the first are spurious, it is usually best to stop TeX after the first error anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: what do mean by "Ignore the number of errors, often all errors after the first are spurious, it is usually best to stop TeX after the first error anyway." ...how would i proceed if errors are there?

Comment: If run in the default interactive mode, then if there is a syntax error tex stops with an error message. If you choose to hit return and let TeX carry on, it makes some essentially arbitrary automatic recovery action to allow it to continue but often you get more "error" messages which are just artefacts of the original error. It is better to stop the run, fix the error reported then restart latex.

Comment: You may use `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`, for changing `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` to `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`. For page layout, you may also use `geometry` package.

Comment: That question is unanswered for quite a while. Can you give a self-answer by now?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I don't think that it would be a nice idea for an inexperienced person to provide answer for this question because I still haven't worked enough with LAtex.

Comment: @cfr Do you want to write a summary of the comments (and maybe more)  as an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think somebody familiar with `IEEEtran` should better write it than me. If nobody wants to, I can write a basic answer and then people can add stuff it they wish. But I've never used that class or `IEEEtrantools`.

Comment: @cfr I think a generic answer would be best, i.e. standard class over `memoir` and `KOMA` over journal and thesis classes.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mix two things:

1. **Design a new document class**, that is, create something like `article.cls` or `ieeetran.cls`. It indeed takes a lot of effort to create a document class.
2. **Change the document class you use**, that is, you have a document that starts with `\documentclass{article}` and you want to change it to a document that starts with `\documentclass{ieeetran}`. This is rather easy; mostly only the document class has to be changed, and then some meta-data input. For instance, each class has a different way of inputting the authors and addresses. Maybe some other small changes will be necessary, but they shouldn't be numerous.